# Invalid DateTime

Tags: powershell, datetime

```
$tmpCreated = dir | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select CreationTime -First 1 
    $tmpCreated = [string]$tmpCreated
    $tmpCreated = $tmpCreated.split("=")[1]
    $tmpCreated = $tmpCreated.split("}")[0]
```

Here is the variable I want to get as a DateTime. I want to compare two dates with this command :

```
$timeDiff = new-timespan –Start $tmpLast –End $tmpCreated
```

`$tmpLast` works fine. But I get an error when i try to launch, saying the -End parameter cannot be used because the `$tmpCreated` conversion failed. But here is the string it contains : `11/30/2015 11:57:01`. So, does someone know what's wrong with this ?

Comment: how do you define/create $tmpLast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CreationTime` property already contains a `DateTime` object, so you simply need to expand the property:

```
$tmpCreated = Get-ChildItem |
              Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending |
              Select-Object -Expand CreationTime -First 1

$timeDiff = New-TimeSpan –Start $tmpLast –End $tmpCreated
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert the date to a string to use it with `New-TimeSpan`

```
$tmpCreated = dir | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select CreationTime -First 1
$timeDiff = new-timespan –Start $tmpLast –End $tmpCreated.CreationTime
```

will do fine.